# How to use custom System namespace in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I have custom classes in `Company.System` namespace. But now I am writing code referencing to `System`, but it is referenced to Company.System. I can use `global::System` to specify .NET System namespace, but when I am creating service installers by visual studio (ie), all classes are referenced to `Company.System` and designers does not work. How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use following code?

```
using Company.System;
```

Use aliases for your own library.

```
using Company.System = Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use aliases to differentiate between one namespace and another: like

```
 using colAlias = System.Collections;

 colAlias::Hashtable test = new colAlias::Hashtable();
```

more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to rename your `Company.System` namespace - it's only going to cause grief for you and the poor maintenance developers down the line.

Another approach is to use the `Aliases` feature (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212(v=vs.80).aspx)  when adding a reference to the assembly(ies) containing the `Company.System` namespace.